# XGBoostModel training failed

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, data-science, xgboost

I have Spark code written in python which uses XGBoost Model for Forecast. Problem I am facing is that code has "for loop" to predict different dataset in loop using XGBoost Model and save trained model.

Code runs fine (no coding error) but after running Model for 10-12 times in loop. It just throws below error and crashes my Spark Application. It doesn't even work with more retry.

Some Troubleshooting what I have done.

-> It is not a data issue. If I restart code with same data it failed for it runs successfully and will fail after some iteration in loop

-> I have tried increasing RAM,Cores and Monitoring CPU/Executors during the run . I don't see any issue. It's not a resource issue.

```
Exception processing forecast: An error occurred while calling o17979.fit.
: ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.java.XGBoostError: XGBoostModel training failed
    at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoost$.ml$dmlc$xgboost4j$scala$spark$XGBoost$$postTrackerReturnProcessing(XGBoost.scala:582)
    at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoost$$anonfun$trainDistributed$2.apply(XGBoost.scala:459)
    at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoost$$anonfun$trainDistributed$2.apply(XGBoost.scala:435)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:296)
    at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoost$.trainDistributed(XGBoost.scala:434)
    at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoostRegressor.train(XGBoostRegressor.scala:190)
    at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoostRegressor.train(XGBoostRegressor.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any pointers on the same would be great . Thanks in advance.

Code

```
    #Loop through all clusters and train model
    for cluster in range(num_clusters):

        logger.info(f'Cluster : {cluster}')
        logger.info(f'Run Start time : {datetime.now()}')

        #SetModel Path and Model Name  
        model_path = 's3a://' + self.s3_bucket + '/'
        model_name = 'Forecast' + 'Cluster_' + str(cluster)             
        logger.info(f'Model Path : {model_path}')
        logger.info(f'Model Name : {model_name}')

        #Filter based on Cluster and cache
        forecast_vector_cluster_df = forecast_vector_df.where(f'cluster={cluster}')
        forecast_vector_cluster_df.cache()
        logger.info(f'Cluster Filter DF Count  : {forecast_vector_cluster_df.count()}')

        #Set Up param for XGBoost Model
        xgbRegressor = XGBoostRegressor(**self.model_parammap) \
                       .setFeaturesCol("features") \
                       .setLabelCol("predict") \
                       .setPredictionCol(f"prediction_{cluster}")

        logger.info('fitting model')
        xgboostModel = xgbRegressor.fit(forecast_vector_cluster_df)

        logger.info('saving model')
        xgboostModel.write().overwrite().save(model_path + model_name)
```

Comment: There is not enough information here to help with your issue. I doubt anyone will be able to offer anything more than general advice. Please include the code you are running and more of the error message.

Comment: Done. Added code. Just want to iterate it't throwing any coding error or it's not a data issue.  Retry runs successfully for same data.

Comment: can you add the executors logs as well?

Answer (score 0):

Check the java version installed on your machine

Switching to java1.8 might solve the issue